# Why does autoencoder not work for dimensionality reduction?

Tags: matlab, dimensionality-reduction, autoencoders

According to my last question, I tried out stacked Autoencoders instead of PCA to reduce the dimensionaly of my problem from ~130 to ~15.

Here comes what I´m doing:

```
hiddenSize1 = 80;
autoenc1 = trainAutoencoder(Data, hiddenSize1, 'MaxEpochs', 400, 'L2WeightRegularization', 0.004,'SparsityRegularization', 4, 'SparsityProportion', 0.15, 'ScaleData', false);
feat1 = encode(autoenc1, Data);

hiddenSize2 = 15;
autoenc2 = trainAutoencoder(feat1, hiddenSize2, 'MaxEpochs', 400, 'L2WeightRegularization', 0.002,'SparsityRegularization', 4, 'SparsityProportion', 0.1, 'ScaleData', false);

autoenc_stacked = stack(autoenc1, autoenc2);

Data_Reduced = autoenc_stacked(Data);
Test_Data_reduced = autoenc_stacked(Test_Data);
```

But it doesnt work at all. The first autoencoder´s performance and gradient is never really decreasing much. Second is doing better. Shouldnt it at least perform equally to PCA?

Comment: In theory there is no reason why auto encoders will always outperform PCA.  Imagine a case in which the variables consisted of 15 uncorrelated variables and then 115 more that were linear combinations of the original 15 with (gaussian) noise added.  PCA would work perfectly to find the linear structure of the variables.  Autoencodings highly non-linear methods would be distinctly inferior.

Comment: But shouldn't it at least produce a somewhat useful result? Or are I doing something wrong? What else could I try?

Comment: How do you test the performance of the reduction? With pca you get orthogonal mappings and taking into account the eigen values decide how much of the variance you want to retain in the reduction.